# element in longest chain and longest antichain

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

> In an arbitrary finite poset, is there necessarily an element that is both in the longest chain and in the largest antichain?

I think it is true. Longest chain contains an element of every largest antichain.

But how to prove it? Maybe a counter-example：

[image]

Comment: Consider the posets with four elements.  I believe there's a counterexample already at that size.

Comment: I came up with a counterexample that I can't draw in the comment. But I added it to the text. Can you help me see if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I realize my counter example is wrong, can you give more hints or counter examples? thanks.

Comment: There aren't that many posets that have only 4 elements. Try a few more examples.